# Find the earliest date in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of dates in column D. I need to find the student with the earliest date, and show the following information in a messagebox:

```
Sub Finddate()
    Dim Mn As Integer
    Mn = Application.Match(Application.Min(Range("D2:D18288")), Range("D2:D18288"), 0)
    MsgBox ("For the student with the earliest date (" & Range("D" & Mn) & ") the following information applies: " & Range("k" & Mn) & ", " & Range("L" & Mn) & " and " & Range("M" & Mn))
End Sub
```

However when i run the Macro it shows the wrong date. The earliest date in the sheet is 31-08-1996, but it says the earliest date is 01-02-2010 and if i write `=min(D2:D18288)` in Excel it finds the right date. But i need it to work in VBA as well. And if i change min to max it also finds the wrong date. But if i instead write:

```
Mn = Application.Match(Application.Max(Range("D2:D18288")), Range("D2:D18288"))
```

It shows the right date but i need to find the min date not the max date and when i change max to min I get a type mismatch error. I really don’t know what is wrong really hope someone can help me!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you want to post code snippets, the way to get them to show up as code is to indent them (at least) four spaces. I've edited your post to do that, and as you can see it's a lot clearer. You might edit it yourself and have a look. Also, to put code inline, you use the ` character on both ends of the code, `like this`.

Comment: The problem is that your match range starts at `2`, but then you reference the row directly as the *match* instead of the *row*.  Either add +1 to `Mn` or start your match range at `1` like `Range("D1:D18288")`

Comment: Thank you so much @tigeravatar! Now I am getting the right date

Answer (score 2):

Your indexing is off by ***1*** ................because the data starts out a **D2** rather than **D1**, Mn points to the cell just above the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

When something like this happens, try to replicate the result, using a small sample. E.g. this one, hoping to return `Peter6` for the smallest info:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim dateRanges As Range
    Set dateRanges = Range("D1:D11")

    Dim mn As Variant
    With Application
        mn = .Match(.Min(dateRanges), dateRanges, 0)
    End With

    MsgBox Range("E" & mn).Value2

End Sub
```

Once it works, try to fix it with your big example.

You will probably notice that `mn` should not be `Integer` as far as `Integer` is up to `32767` and this parsed to a date is `16-September-1989`, which is long time ago. In your case it is not an error, because you are not referencing `mn` directly to a date, but it may happen at a later.